# Bivariate model and 'predict.rma()' function ('metafor' package)

Tags: r, plot, metafor

Suppose I have the following model result:

```
> summary(msa_res@objects[[1]])

Model Results:

         estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub     
intrcpt    0.9397  0.0667  14.0850  <.0001   0.8090   1.0705  ***
MAT_e     -0.0079  0.0035  -2.2691  0.0233  -0.0147  -0.0011    *
Naddl     -0.0385  0.0133  -2.9005  0.0037  -0.0645  -0.0125   **
```

I want to plot regression lines using the predict function for `MAT_e` and `Naddl` moderators:

```
preds_MAT_e <- predict(msa_res@objects[[1]], newmods=c(-5:30))
preds_Naddl <- predict(msa_res@objects[[1]], newmods=c(1:6))
```

But I get this type of error:

```
Error in predict.rma(msa_res@objects[[1]], newmods = c(-5:30)) : 
  Dimensions of 'newmods' do not match dimensions of the model.
```

I guess this is because I am not specifying which moderator should be considered by predict() function. Note that the function above works fine for univariate models e.g. with MAT_e only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have two predictors, you need to specify values for both predictors. So, for example:

```
predict(msa_res@objects[[1]], newmods=cbind(-5:30, 1))
```

or

```
predict(msa_res@objects[[1]], newmods=cbind(10, 1:6))
```

So you can hold one predictor constant while varying the other.